# Time series forecast from STL using ARIMA method for specific order

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, seasonality

I am trying to forecast daily sales and have found that for the seasonally adjusted component a non-seasonal ARIMA (3,1,6) and a seasonal naive for seasonal component gives me the best result.

How can I use `stlf` or `stlm` functions to specify my order (3,1,6) in ARIMA method?

Currently, I am forecasting both components separately and merging them to obtain my forecasts.

Comment: I do not think you can do both using just `stlf` or `stlm`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example.

```
fit <- stlm(USAccDeaths, modelfunction=Arima, order=c(3,1,6))
fc <- forecast(fit)
plot(fc)
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, Prof. @Hyndman. A big fan of your work! I am starting out with time-series forecasting and your book (Forecasting: principles and practice) has been a very informative guide.

Comment: I am getting slightly different results from my earlier approach (`stl` on timeseries followed by non-seasonal ARIMA (3,1,6) on seasadj component and seasonal naive on seasonal component) and from `stlm` function. Any particular reason for it?

Comment: Possible using different versions of the package?